# should nested class be declared as static if only used in wrapper clas

Tags: java, static, inner-classes, nested-class

Sample code:

```
class A {
    public doSomethingFancy() {
         .....
         doJOb();
    }
    private doJob() {
        B b  = new B();
    }

    private class B {
    }
}
```

class `B` is only needed for class `A`.Or is only used in class `A`.

Is there need to declare class `B` as `static` ? yes/no Why?

Comment: "Inner class declared as static" is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0):

You declare B static if it doesn't need access to the A object it was created for.

You declare B private if only A needs to use it, or other clients only use it via its implemented interfaces.

Comment: So, in my case B should be static and private